# The probability distribution function raised to a power is also a probability distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I got this tutorial question and I had no clue about how to prove this:

Let $\,F(x)\,$ be a distribution function and $\,r\,$ a positive integer.

Show that $\,F(x)^r\,$ is also a distribution function

Comment: Hint: Which properties qualify a function $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be a distribution function?

Comment: Thanks ! Its non-decreasing. F(-infinity) = 0 and F(infinity) = 1. These still hold when exponentiated if r is positive. This was pretty obvious - I was being stupid

Comment: These are not sufficient to guarantee that F is a distribution function. There is still one more property...

Comment: @did I remember similar story from another previous question)

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Do you? :-))

Comment: @did of course))

Comment: hope you were referring to continuous from the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community answer:

> Hint: Which properties qualify a function $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be a distribution function? – did
>
> It's non-decreasing. $F(-\infty) = 0$ and $F(\infty) = 1$. These still hold when exponentiated if $r$ is positive.  – user929404
>
> These are not sufficient to guarantee that F is a distribution function. There is still one more property... – did
>
> continuous from the right - user929404